# Postman getting 404 error for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to learn asp.net core so according [official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code) i installed it's sdk and create simple web api by this command:

```
dotnet new webapi -o TodoApi
```

My ide is vscode. 
This is my controller class :

```
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        [HttpGet("api/cities")]
        public JsonResult GetCities(){
            return new JsonResult(new List<object>(){
                new {id=1, name = "new york city"},
                new {id = 2 , name = "gorgan"}
            });
        }

    }
}
```

I added `GetCities` method in this example.In postman when i use

```
https://localhost:5001/api/values
```

I got result :

```
[
    "value1",
    "value2"
]
```

but when i call my method that i have already added to controller, in postamn

```
https://localhost:5001/api/cities
```

I got `404 Not Found` and i have to use this url `https://localhost:5001/api/values/api/cities` to got right answer?

What is a problem? and how could i fix that?

This is setting:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": false, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:34842",
      "sslPort": 44370
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TodoApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And dotnet info:

```
groot@groot-Product:~$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.700
 Commit:    c2ef055a0f

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.11
  Commit:  d6a5616240

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.700 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
groot@groot-Product:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Controller name is ValuesController. ASP.Net uses the controller name for the path. So in this case you should call

```
api/values/GetCities
```

and remove the

```
[HttpGet("api/cities")]
```

attribute from your method.

If you want the path to be

```
GET api/cities
```

Create a new controller, and copy your code into that controller renaming your method to `Get()` then sit back and let the code do the routing for you.

Comment: When i remove `[HttpGet("api/cities")]` and call `https://localhost:5001/api/values/GetCities ` i got `{
    "id": [
        "The value 'GetCities' is not valid."
    ]
}` in postman ? @philpeters

Comment: I hadn't spotted your second method was also a Get so what's happening is because of the route on there `api/values/5` GetCities is actually being passed as an id to that method, however that is expecting an int and therefore cannot be parsed. Ideally you should create a new controller for this or remove those other methods and rename this controller.

Comment: I *think* that your path with the route set (`[HttpGet("api/cities")]`) would actually be `api/values/api/cities` because it concatenates the routes in the controller path. Some docs on this type of 'Conventional Routing' can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#conventional-routing)